# Use ini_set functions for [custom].ini files except php.ini settings

Tags: ini, ini-set

I created a custom ini file for keep some array details. Not used for configuration like values. Then I would like to update or remove sections from this files.

Currently I used **parse_ini_file** function and update the array and save that array to ini file. But my file is a large file and this process may happen every second. So i want to update each sections without file open and save. That means I am looking a function like **ini_set**.

- test_data1 = first test
- test_data2 = second test
- test_data3 = third
- test_data4 = fourth test
- test_data5 = fifth test

Some sections from my ini file mention above. How can I edit these each sections by program. I know one solution like; read the sections as an array, make the changes done to the array and save that array to the ini file. Any body have any other idea?

Comment: Any body have an idea, please help me :)

Comment: **James Z**   Thank you for the correction. :)